# How do i print names in a .txt file without repeating the names?

Tags: python

This is the best i can do

```
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt")
for x in Nombres:
    print(x.rstrip())
```

But the names do repeat?

How can i filter them or just make the machine doesn't add the repeated name to the printout?

Comment: Put them in a set and / or check if they are already contained in that set!?

Answer (score 2):

A way to use is creating a set of already printed names like:

```
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt")
printed_names = set()
for x in Nombres:
    if x not in printed_names:
        print(x.rstrip())
        printed_names.add(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the strings to set and after that print the set content.

```py
content = set()
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt") 
for x in Nombres:
    content.add(x.rstrip())  
for i in content:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Append it to list or set ,based on the condition.

```
names = []
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt") 
for x in Nombres:
     if x not in names 
     names.append(x.rstrip())
print(*names)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st solution : put all the names inside a list, then convert it to a set .

2nd solution : append the printed names inside a list and before printing check if the name is not in the printed list

Answer (score -1):

This?

```
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt")
for i,x in enumerate(Nombres):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(x.rstrip())
```

edit: or

```
Nombres = open("Nombres.txt")
for x Nombres:
    print(x.split()[0])
```

depending on if they are separated by space / newline, and if they are subsequent, as pointed out by the comments.

Comment: I don't think this approach is actually correct. The original post doesn't state that double entries are in subsequent order.